# JSX Element type 'void' is not a constructor function for JSX elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What am I doing wrong here?

It doesn't like the way I am calling `Items`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

interface LinkedItemProps {
    icon: string;
    title: string;
}

export const Items = ({icon, title}: LinkedItemProps) => {
    <div>
        <div className="nav-menu-link-icon">
            {icon}
        </div>
        <div className="nav-menu-link-label">
            {title}
        </div>
    </div>
}

export default class LinkedItems extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Link
                to={this.props.link}
                title={this.props.title}
                onClick={this.props.afterClick}
            >
                <Items icon={this.props.icon} title={this.props.title} /> //error
            </Link>
    )}
}
```

P.S. Thank you [Shubham Khatri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928186/shubham-khatri) for marking this as a duplicate of a question that does not remotely resemble what I asked.

Comment: What is the error that you receive

Comment: Probably not related to your current error, but you've misspelled `title` as `tilte` at the end of your code.

Comment: @Hafiz, What do you mean by your comment, the Duplicate question has had the same issue

Comment: sure... and you asked me earlier `"What is the error that you receive"`. Read the title, please lol

Comment: @HafizTemuri, i can reopen your ques but it will be better to use flag 'reopen' and ask people to reopen your ques :)

Comment: @MayankShukla, That's fine. I got the answer that I was looking for. I was a bit pissed that someone marked a duplicate when it is not. Anyways, thanks :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`Items` is an arrow function with `{}` which means you have to explicitly give it a `return` statement:

```
export const Items = ({icon, title}: LinkedItemProps) => {
  return ( // <------ must return here
    <div>
      <div className="nav-menu-link-icon">
        {icon}
      </div>
      <div className="nav-menu-link-label">
        {title}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you do not, then the `Items` just returns `undefined` which is an empty value and thus

```
JSX Element type 'void' is not a constructor function for JSX elements"
```

For a bit cleaner code, you can replace the `{}` with `()` completely:

```
export const Items = ({icon, title}: LinkedItemProps) => ( 
  <div>
    <div className="nav-menu-link-icon">
      {icon}
    </div>
    <div className="nav-menu-link-label">
      {title}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: You are right... `{ }` were the culprit. Thanks :)